# Time-Taken; Taken Time; Used Time

Tags: phrases, expressions, word-usage

I have created a tool/database for the measurement of the time which is used to complete a specific process/workflow in my company.

One of the columns shows the time the workflow used to be completed, and one the time used with interruption. For example the workflow is to write a letter. I take the time from putting the paper in the machine until pulling it out of it. The total time is 5 minutes. But sometimes the phone rings, then I need to stop the time and so on. So the real time is not 5 but 10 minutes. To make a long story short. How can I name these two columns. Even in my own language I do not have a proper name.

Thankful for any hints
Greetz from Germany
Armin

Comment: "Working time" / "Total time"?

Comment: *Active/Elapsed* time?

Comment: Good as well! Now I have to make a decision.

Comment: In project management, "effort" is the time spent on the work and "elapsed time" is the time from start to finish. There is also an intermediate term "duration" which does not include weekends or holidays. In computing, equivalent terms are "cpu time" ("process time") and "real time" ("run time").

Comment: Time spent? Or isn't [time money](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf) any more?

Comment: Very good Explanation. Thank you.
@JohnLawler: Completely right. :D